# How to access data through Provider.of

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to figure out how to get data through a Provider, but I'm stuck.

my main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<UserBocorp>(
          create: (context) => UserBocorp(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: IsLogin(),
        routes: {
          LoginPage.routeName: (ctx) => LoginPage(),
          HomePage.routeName: (ctx) => HomePage(),
          Article.routeName: (ctx) => Article(),
          Staffs.routeName: (ctx) => Staffs(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But as soon as I want to get data in another widget I get null

my userBocorp class:

```
class UserBocorp extends ChangeNotifier {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String lastname;
  final String photo;
  final int typeUser;

  UserBocorp({this.id, this.name, this.lastname, this.photo, this.typeUser});

  factory UserBocorp.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserBocorp(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      lastname: json['lastname'],
      photo: json['avatar'],
      typeUser: json['type'],
    );
  }

  UserBocorp jsonresponse;

  Future<UserBocorp> createAlbum() async {
    final http.Response response = await http.post(
      'https://test.com/api/getUserName',
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'title': 'test@test.com',
      }),
    );

    final jsonresponse = json.decode(response.body);

    notifyListeners();
    return UserBocorp.fromJson(jsonresponse[0]);
  }
}
```

How can I get user data in any other widgets? I would be grateful for any help

I am getting the data for the first time in the main page widget return

```
FutureBuilder <UserBocorp> (
      future: Provider.of <UserBocorp> (context, listen: false) .createAlbum (),
```

It displays the data fine, but as soon as I want to access the same data in another widget via:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var user = Provider.of<UserBocorp>(context);
    return Drawer(
```

I just get null in my data without any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding get to my class

```
var _userInfo;
    
get userInfo => _userInfo;
    
void setUserInfo(info) {
    _userInfo = info;
}
```

and after receiving the answer:

```
setUserInfo(UserBocorp.fromJson(jsonresponse[0]));
```

Everything works fine now

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a "Consumer" who uses that data.

Have a look at: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple.

In few words, something like this:

```
return Consumer<UserBocorp>(
  builder: (context, user, child) {
    return Text("Name: ${user.name}");
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I keep getting null even so

Comment: If you get a null with no errors, probably your data are null and you are not popolating them. In fact, you just have something like `String name;` but what if you don't properly init it? If will be null.

Comment: He mentioned that, data is getting in main widget

Comment: It may depends on the context he uses to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` instead of `ChangeNotifierProvider`

```
ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: UserBocorp()),
```